# Why are strict inequalities stronger than non-strict inequalities?

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm working with induction proofs involving inequalities and I am encountering example proofs that wish to show things of the sort, $n!\le\ n^n$ for every positive integer. The proof given in the inductive step is, $(n+1)!$ $=$ $(n+1)\dot\ n!$ $\le$ $(n+1)n^n$$\lt$ $(n+1)(n+1)^n$ $=$ $(n+1)^{n+1}$ I'm not quite clear why the strict inequality was admissible in the proof, if I'm trying to show $n!\le\ n^n$, rather than $n!\lt\ n^n$. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What this shows is that for $n>1$ it is true that $n! < n^n$.

Comment: BTW $(n+1)(n+1)^n = (n+1)^{n+1}$ in the last part of your inductive step.

Comment: So my text is wrong in stating that this demonstrates $n\le n^n$ for all positive integers?

Comment: No, your text is not wrong, if you mean that $n!\leq n^n$?  See the answer by Twink below. If we know $a < b$ then $a \leq b$ is a true statement. But not the other way around.

Comment: Then this example could have used the non-strict inequality throughout the entire inductive step?

Answer (score 3):

You can change $<$ by $\leq$ but not $\leq$ by $<$.

For example, we have $1 < 2$, so $1 \leq 2$ is also true.

On the other hand, we have $1 \leq 1$, but it's not true that $1 < 1$.

Also, you proved $n! < n^n$ for $n > 1$, but this is not true for every positive integer, since for $n=1$ we get the equality. But it's true that $n! \leq n^n$ for every positive integer $n$.