# If $<$ is a "strict inequality", what do we call $\leq$?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term or phrase better than "non-strict"?

Comment: I always called them "non-strict inequality" and hope it's correct..

Comment: I think "not-necessarily strict" is unfortunately the best we can do in English.

Comment: I've seen the non-strict inequalities called "*inclusive inequalities*". A quick search finds examples of this usage in math books, but it doesn't appear to be widespread.

Comment: In Italy we use *debole*, that stands for *weak*, but maybe that is not very common in English.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: In French we use *inégalité large* as opposed to *inégalité stricte*. Note that by default *inégalité* stands for *inégalité large*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General expression/phrase for "less / greater than or equal to"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270823/general-expression-phrase-for-less-greater-than-or-equal-to)

Comment: @Scexit I suggest instead of marking this question a duplicate, we mark the *other* question a duplicate because this one now has an answer (from you) that actually answers the question (while the other is "answered" with something that avoids the actual question), and besides, this question was asked first.

Answer (score 2):

Why hasn't anyone mooted ["weak inequality"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505351)? Or are you shunning "weak inequality" too?

Richard Earl, James Nicholson, [*The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Mathematics* (6 ed. 2021)](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780198845355.001.0001/acref-9780198845355-e-1447?rskey=xEPQw9&result=1)

> Inequalities involving < and > are called ‘strict’, and those involving ≤ and ≥ are termed ‘weak’.

[Ron Aharoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Aharoni), *Algebra For Parents: A Book For Grown-ups About Middle School Mathematics* (2021), [p. 96](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Algebra_For_Parents_A_Book_For_Grown_ups/geIZEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Weak+inequality%22+google+books&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover).

> ##### Inequalities
>
> Let us recall two notations. "x < 3" means that x is smaller than 3 ― strictly
> so, namely equality is not allowed. If we wish to allow also equality, we write
> "x ≤ 3". The latter is called "weak inequality".

Stan Gibilisco, *Everyday Math Demystified* (2004), [p. 5](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Everyday_Math_Demystified/956rLGvZcN8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Weak+inequality%22+google+books+math&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover).

[image]