# General expression/phrase for "less / greater than or equal to"?

Tags: terminology

There is the expression / phrase "strict inequality" for mathematical expressions like -2 < 1 or 1/2 > - 1/2.

Is there an equivalent "short" expression where the equality is included in the relation? "Unstrict inequality" does not "feel" right.

"Inequality" seems too broad because it covers both cases: "less/greater than" " less/greater than or equal to".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the phrase nearly always used is "non-strict inequality". I think the phrase "lax inequality" is also used, quite often, but there is a danger of confusion with the name of the mathematician Peter Lax!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $&lt;$ is a "strict inequality", what do we call $\leq$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930831/if-is-a-strict-inequality-what-do-we-call-leq)

Answer (score 2):

$x\leq y$ is "$x$ is at most $y$".

$x\geq y$ is "$x$ is at least $y$".

Answer (score 1):

Weak Inequality! See Definition 1.3.3 at the top of page 9, in Hugo D. Junghenn's *A Course in Real Analysis* (2015).

> [The inequality a ≤ b is sometimes called ***weak inequality*** in contrast to ***strict inequality*** a < b.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_in_Real_Analysis/nE63BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22weak+inequality%22+definition&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover)

See the first paragraph on page 28, of Mark Bridger's *Real Analysis : A Constructive Approach Through Interval Arithmetic* (2019).

> [It is also useful to have a notion of weak inequality, usually denoted ≤.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Real_Analysis_A_Constructive_Approach_Th/LG2hDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22weak+inequality%22+definition&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover)